# rendering error after enabling salesforce to salesforce data migration

Tags: salesforce2salesforce, data-migration

after enabling salesforce to salesforce migration.

It gives me error while displaying all fields of my custom object on visual-force page.

```
public class MyClass {
   public Map<String,String> abc{get;set;}
   public test() {
       String query = 'select id,name,connectionreceivedid,connectionsentid from customObject__c';
       List<customObject__c> cList = Database.query(query);
       customObject__c i = cList[0];
       abc = new Map<String,String>();
       abc.put('id', String.valueOf(i.id));
       abc.put('name', String.valueOf(i.name));
       abc.put('connectionreceivedid', String.valueOf(i.connectionreceivedid));
       abc.put('connectionsentid', String.valueOf(i.connectionsentid));
   }
}
```

try to display above fields on visual-force page.